# What to do about voting fraud?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I've been a Stack Overflow member for a while now, and all has gone well so far. But recently I got a downvote on each of two of my very old questions (in the same day), I thought it was rather strange but also that it might just be a coincidence.

Then I got another downvote on one of my old questions, and today, this:

[image: Downvotes everywhere!]

Coincidence? Not so much.

One downvote on five answers, all within one minute. The user couldn't have read all the answers and decided that they were bad in that small amount of time.

So what can be done about this? Can the mods do anything, can I do anything?

Comment: This is the normal punishment for refusing to immediately and completely provide a thorough and comprehensive homework answer, ready for copypasta.

Comment: *What to do about voting fraud?* You just spit at them and let the Serial Voting Regulation Script take care of it.

Comment: Didn't know about this, and I didn't find anything through The Google (bad search terms I guess). Thanks guys. :)